# Javascript-POST not working

Tags: javascript, post

```
  onSubmit: function(invalid, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!invalid)
    {
        alert("test");
        $.post('login.php', this.$form.serialize(), function(response) {
    // asdasd
  }, 'json');
    }
   }
```

I get the alert box but the post doesn't seem to work. Is there anything clearly wrong in the above code?

I am using IdealForms.

Comment: How do you know that post doesn't work? Did you check the console? Is it making any requests?

Comment: as i see post is working 'Request URL:http://xacnr.com/default/secure/ajax.php
Request Headers CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown.
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://xacnr.com
Referer:http://xacnr.com/default/secure/login.php?action=login
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
username:w213we2323'

Comment: I used to use Firebug, now I don't have any tool.Cloud you please check for me, I have added the link.Meanwhile, let me download firefox and firebug. EDIT:@Vasil, thats for the username and it works.The problem is with the submit button.

Comment: try to use ajax call instead of $.post

Comment: I get a 200, with HTML result. <h3>Direct Access is restricted.</h3>For security reasons, we do not allow direct access.Please login through the home page. I'm using native Firefox debug tool (not firebug).

Comment: What are you expecting the code to do? You haven't written anything inside the function

Comment: alert the response inside the function

Comment: @progysm you need to specify action=login to work! at usr3368817 I have nothing to deal with the response.I just want to send the form data using post to a php file.

Comment: The error must be somewhere on your server side, the request works fine, but this is the response http://i.imgur.com/4MRBA6Z.png

Comment: Console shows that post is working.I expected the page to refresh and open the page which was sent by post :/  Should I reload the page manually?

Comment: Why would you expect the page to reload? What's the purpose of AJAX if you reload the page? Plus you prevented the default submit behavior. Send JSON from PHP and do what you need to do with the response in the success callback.

Comment: Thanks it worked!I removed the prevent default.

Comment: Yeah but if you do that, then you're not using AJAX... See if my answer helps.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50000/discussion-between-yashas-samaga-and-elclanrs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request works, there must be an issue in your server side code. Make sure that:

1) `login.php` exists and it's in the right path.

2) Your PHP script echos JSON. Try a simple test script:

```
<?php
// login.php
echo json_encode(array('value' => true)); // send as JSON
```

Then in JavaScript log the response to the console (press F12 or Cmd+Shift+I):

```
onSubmit: function(invalid, e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(!invalid) {
    $.post('login.php', this.$form.serialize(), function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }, 'json'); // read as JSON
  }
}
```

The console should output an object `{value: true}`.

PS: I'm the developer of Ideal Forms.

Comment: POST http://xacnr.com/default/secure/p.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 438ms]
[object Object] and in p.php(changed the name) <?php
// login.php
echo json_encode(array('value' => true)); exit; ?>

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is call JQuery, and use code like this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "login.php",
   data: $(this).serialize(),
   success: function() {
     alert('success');
   }
});
```

Comment: This won't work. `this` is not the form, is the IdealForms instance. `$.post` works fine in OP's site.